# Рандомайзер выводит одинаковые числа

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Для генерации случайных чисел использую `rand()` перед этим иницииирую таймер `srand(time(NULL));`, но при каждом перезапуске программы числа одинаковые...
Инициирую за телом цикла, вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int randomDigits[7] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << randomDigits[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где здесь `rand()`? В этом коде вы не используете ГСЧ вовсе...

Comment: Прошу прощения, я пробовал использовать rand() в этом примере его нет, но все же помогите разобраться с этим примером

Comment: С чем именно разобраться? Этот код будет выводить нули. Как и должен.

Comment: Ну как же вам можно помочь, если вы ничего не спрашиваете? :) Прямо как в "Иван Васильевич меняет профессию" - "да как же тебя понять, коли ты ничего не говоришь?":)

Comment: Да именно, а почему, почему он выводит "0" ?

Comment: Инициализатор `= {}` обнуляет массив.

Comment: Ну вы же сами инициировали массив `int randomDigits[7] = {};`

Comment: Я уже начинаю понимать, что непряморукий, как поправить(код)?

Comment: Даже если вы уберете инициализатор - это еще не значит, что у вас будут истинно случайные числа :)

Comment: Да что вы хотите-то получить, скажите!

Comment: Да конечно я понимаю, там псевдослучайные

Comment: @ДанилаБайрамгалеев Про `rand()` почитайте.

Comment: Там будет МУСОР. Просто то, что осталось в памяти с последнего обращения к ней, и не более того. Случайные/псевдослучайные числа имеют определенные статистические характеристики; мусор их не имеет.

Comment: Я хочу получать список случайных чисел, когда убираю инициализатор получаю "-858993460", что делать?

Comment: Если пишите на C++, то лучше использовать `<random>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну добавьте вот такой цикл...

```
int randomDigits[7] = {};

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    randomDigits[i] = rand();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В этом объявлении

```
int randomDigits[7] = {};
```

вы инициализировали все элементы массива нулем.

Более нигде в программе вы не изменяли значения элементов массива.

Если вы хотите задать значения элементов массива случайными числами (например, цифрами от 0 до 10 исключительно), то вам следует использовать стандартную C функцию. `rand`, объявленную в заголовке `<cstdlib>`.

У вас имеется несколько подходов.

Например, обычный `for` цикл.

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( randomDigits ) / sizeof( *randomDigits ); i++ )
{
    randomDigits[[i] = std::rand() % 10;
}
```

Вместо выражения `sizeof( randomDigits ) / sizeof( *randomDigits )` вы могли бы в C++17 использовать стандартную функцию  `std::size`, объявленную в заголовке `<iterator>`. Например,

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

// ...

for( size_t i = 0; i < std::size( randomDigits ); i++ )
{
    randomDigits[[i] = std::rand() % 10;
}
```

Также вы могли бы использовать предложение `for` на основе диапазонов. Например,

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

for( auto &item : randomDigits )
{
    item = std::rand() % 10;
}
```

И, наконец, вы могли бы использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::generate`. Например,

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std::generate( std::begin( randomDigits ), std::end( randomDigits ), 
               [] { return std::rand() % 10; } );
```